# Salesforce- Trigger - Deleting object

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex-code

Hello fellow code lovers, I am attempting to learn apex code and stuck on a problem. Since most of you guys here are avid code lovers and excited about problem solving, I figured I could ran by problem by.

I am attempting to Create a Trigger on an object called Book that does the following:
On Delete, all associated Chapters are also deleted
There is also an object named Chapter that is has a lookup to book.

Here is my attempt. This is my first ever attempt at apex so please be patient. Is anyone willing to dabble in this piece of code?

```
 trigger DeleteChaptersTrigger on Book__c (before delete) {
 List<Book__c> book = Trigger.old;
 List<Chapter__c> chapters = new List<Chapter__c>();
 Set set = new Set();

  for (Book__c b :books){
  if ()
   }
 }
```

Comment: Do you have full control over the account and its design/setup?

Comment: @GerardSexton Yes I do.

Answer (score 3):

You need to write all trigger with consideration that the trigger might be processing many records at any one time so you need to [bulkify your trigger code.](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Best_Practice%3a_Bulkify_Your_Code)

[Here are the variables that available on the trigger object.](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm)

You want to get all the record ids that will be deleted. Use the `keyset` method on the `oldmap` to get this info without looping and creating your own collection. Then you can just delete the records returned from the query.

```
trigger DeleteChaptersTrigger on Book__c (before delete) {
    Set<string> bookids = Trigger.oldMap.keyset();
    delete [SELECT Id FROM Chapter__c WHERE Book__c IN :bookids];     
}
```

Apex code is unlike other languages where it gets confused with reuse of used words, like set as a variable name. Apex is also case insensitive.

Comment: +1 but you don't need keyset while binding like that, you can bind collection and it will be cast down to collection of Ids automatically :)

Comment: @eyescream Oh, its an automatic cast?  So `delete [SELECT Id FROM Chapter__c WHERE Book__c IN :Trigger.old];` is also valid?

Comment: Yep :)  http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_SOQL_variables.htm and search for "IN-bind"

Answer (score 2):

Since you have full control, I recommend changing the way your custom objects are related to each other.

A chapter has no meaning/value without a book so we want to change the relationship between the two.

Remove the lookup on the Chapter object and replace it with a master-detail. When a master record gets deleted, Salesforce automatically deletes the detail related records. This is what you want, and without coding.

Comment: @Gerald Sexton I am actually following an exercise. and that it asked for a lookup.

Comment: well then, that information affects the type of answer that can be given.